# Separar Item clickable em Layout android

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho uma ListView, e um layout do item do adapter que segue a imagem básica dele

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Problema é que quando eu clico em qualquer área do item, na lista, todo componente é "selecionado"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria de obter o efeito de Ação 1, Ação 2 e Descrição separados.

Por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Layout XML:

```
...
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp">

        <!--descrição-->
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:id="@+id/txtDescricao"
                android:text="Descricao" />

        <!--este é o "separador" horizontal-->
        <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="100"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

            <!--Tentei colocar um Linear Layout "fora" e marcar clickable = true -->
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                          android:layout_weight="50"
                          android:clickable="true"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:id="@+id/txtAcao1"
                        android:text="Acao 1" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <!--este é o "separador" vertical entre ação 1 e ação 2-->
            <View
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="50"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/txtAcao2"
                    android:text="Acao 2" />

        </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Tentei também adicionar um `setOnClickListener` no Ação1 e Ação2, mas não funcionou

Segue a classe .java

```
//ViewHolder
    static class ViewHolderItem {
            public TextView txtAcao1;
            public TextView txtAcao2;
            public View txtDescricao;
        }

//Adapter
 class RoteiroAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

            private Context mContext = null;
            private List<ItemRoteiro> mListaRoteiro = null;

            public RoteiroAdapter(Context context, List<ItemRoteiro> lista){
                this.mContext = context;
                this.mListaRoteiro = lista;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mListaRoteiro.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return mListaRoteiro.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

                if(convertView == null){

                    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_roteiro, parent, false);

                    viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
                    viewHolder.txtAcao1= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAcao1);
                    viewHolder.txtAcao2= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtAcao2);
                    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                }
                else{
                    viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
                }

                ItemRoteiro item = mListaRoteiro.get(position);

                if(item != null) {

                    viewHolder.txtAcao1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                        }
                    });
                }
                 return convertView;
            }
        }
```

Alguém sabe como obter este efeito??

Obrigado!!

Comment: Como você trata isso na activity?

Comment: instancia cada layout(são 2 ações; portanto, 2 layouts diferentes) e dá clickListener no layout.

Comment: @ReginaldoRigo editei e postei o código da activity

Comment: @Mr_Anderson, obrigado pela ajuda, vou testar aqui e aviso o resultado..

Comment: @Mr_Anderson também não funcionou.. Já fiz muitos testes nenhum tive sucesso...

Comment: Estranho, pq se é uma lista customizada, então deveria funcionar, assim como um cardview que contém uma imagem com alguns botoes dentro...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Da um ID pro seu LinearLayout e usa o click via Java nele.

Exemplo:

XML

```
<LinearLayout 
     android:id="@+id/acao1"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight="50"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">
```

JAVA

```
LinearLayout acao1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.acao1);
acao1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
```

Em todos os itens no XML inserir:

```
 android:clickable="false"
```

E o layout aonde deseja ter o efeito do "click"

```
 android:clickable="true"
 android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: Obrigado @Leonardo Dias pela ajuda, testei aqui, o que ocorre agora, é que quando pressiono em Acao1 ou Acao2 não acontece nada na tela (o onClickListener é chamado normalmente), porém se pressiono na descrição todo item é marcado. Mas já foi um avanço..

Comment: Tenta colocar o **android:clickable="false"** no TextView da descrição

Comment: Testei, tentei também colocar o `android:duplicateParentState="true"`, que achei, mas não está funcionando.. Estou fazendo testes..

Comment: Obrigado @LeonardoDias, bastou adicionar o `android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`, no linearLayout e `android:clickable=true` nos linearLayout e funcinou!!!